# text appears randomly with php

Tags: php

i want to make some simple script, So I want the script that I created can bring up the text and can also remove the text, so text will appear randomly, for example

first visit on index.php

```
HELLO WORLD
```

second visit on index.php

```
HELLO WORLD
```

third visit on index.php

```
-nothing-
```

fourth visit on index.php

```
-nothing-
```

fifth visit on index.php

```
HELLO WORLD
```

for example as above, but I do not know how the script should I make, is there any suggestion about this problem? thank you

Comment: WHAT you have tried so far? Add that in your question. You can use `SESSION`,`counter` and `if-else` to get the thing done

Comment: If you simply want to randomly display a message, use some php's providden random functions then ?

Comment: Maybe `echo rand(0,1) ? 'HELLO WORLD' : '';` ?

Comment: You can put strings in an array - `array('HELLO WORLD', '', 'string 3')`. Then use `rand(....)` as array key to access and output each string randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's `rand()` to generate a random integer. Since there are only two options here, which is to display `"HELLO WORLD"` or not display anything, we can ask `rand()` to generate two different numbers - typically `0` and `1`.

If the output of `rand()` is `1`, for example, then you can `echo "HELLO WORLD"`

```
if (rand(0, 1) == 1) {
    echo "HELLO WORLD";
}
```